# DrEdit sample fails to open txt file

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I copied a .txt file to my google drive and am trying to open it with the DrEdit C# sample.  When I try to open the file, the ASP.NET server gets a 403 forbidden response from the server.  The body of the response says:

`The authenticated user has not installed the app with client id 229016086359-m19r73ngg9pr863m5h7eso151kcc2uut.apps.googleusercontent.com [403]`

I am also not able to save a new file using the sample either.  I think I am close, but am not sure what is causing this problem.  The documentation is not completely clear about the configuration settings so I probably got one of them wrong, here is what I am doing:

1. ClientCredentials.cs - CLIENT_ID - Set to the "Client ID" value in the "Client ID for Drive SDK" section on the "API Access" page
2. ClientCredentials.cs - CLIENT_SECRET - Set to the "Client secret" value in the "Client ID for Drive SDK" section on the "API Access" page
3. ClientCredentials.cs - REDIRECT_URI - Set to the base URL for my ASP.NET application
4. dredit.js - setAppId('') on line 104 - set to the value of "App Id:" on the Drive SDK page
5. manifest.json - app_console_project_id - set to the value of "App Id:" on the Drive SDK page

I did upload the app via the chrome web store, published to test accounts and installed the app from the chrome web store.  Here is what I am doing:

1. Launching the app (from web store or via URL).
2. Allow access on the request for permission screen
3. Close the edit details dialog for untitled.txt
4. Click the open button - it shows the text file I coped to google drive from Windows
5. Double click the text file, it shows the empty edit screen with a button "Loading" at the top.  The network traffic shows I am getting 500 internal server error and the response body shows 403 is being returned from google drive to the ASP.NET application

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong Client ID and Secret.

Copy the values from the "Client ID for web applications" section in the APIs Console instead of those in the "Client ID for Drive SDK" section.

We are updating our docs to make this step more clear, thanks!

Comment: Correct - I was using the "Client ID For Drive SDK Section".  I was using that because I only had that and a service account id (which doesn't have a secret).  Because of your reply, I have now created a Client Id for Web Applications and am using that.  I am still getting the same error, but the ID is now for the Client Id for Web Applications.  I am wondering if I did something wrong on the publishing step now....

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have enabled both the Google Drive API and the SDK in the APIs Console.

More suggestions at [Why am I getting "The authenticated user has not installed the app with client id" error when using the Google Drive API natively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345904/why-am-i-getting-the-authenticated-user-has-not-installed-the-app-with-client-i) and [Google Drive authentication issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362853/google-drive-authentication-issues)

Comment: I have set both "Drive API" and "Drive SDK" to "On" status in the services page in the API console - is that what you mean by enabling them?  Thanks for linking those articles, but I had already read them and was unable to resolve the issue